# Another Generalization of a Problem of Steinhaus

Tags: co.combinatorics

In his book of problems from elementary mathematics Hugo Steinhaus asked the following:

Is it possible to find an infinite sequence of real numbers $x_1,x_2,...$, such that 
$x_1$ lies in the interval [0,1); each of $x_1,x_2$ lies in a different interval from among [0,$\frac{1}{2}$), [$\frac{1}{2}$,1); each of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ lies in a different interval from among [0,$\frac{1}{3}$), [$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{2}{3}$),[$\frac{2}{3}$,1), ...? Or if not how long can such a sequence be?

Another way to ask the same question is:

Does there exist for every positive integer N a  sequence of real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_N$ such that for every n in {1,...,N} and every k in {1,...,n} we have

$\frac{k-1}{n}$ <= $x_i$ <$\frac{k}{n} $ for some i in {1,...,n}?  If not, what is the greatest possible N?

Using a computer this is easy enough to do.  The answer is that no more than 17 such points can be found.  See M. Warmus, A Supplementary Note on the Irregularities of Distributions. Journal of Number Theory 8, 260-263 (1976).

I've tried to extend this problem in several different ways, but so far the searches involved have been too great for my computer.  I think that there is a chance to compute the following generalization.

How long a sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_N$ can one find such that $x_1$ lies in the interval [0,1);  each of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ lies in a different interval from among [0,$\frac{1}{3}$), [$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{2}{3}$),[$\frac{2}{3}$,1); each of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ lies in a different interval from among [0,$\frac{1}{5}$), [$\frac{1}{5}$,$\frac{2}{5}$),[$\frac{2}{5}$,$\frac{3}{5}$),[$\frac{3}{5}$,$\frac{4}{5}$),[$\frac{4}{5}$,1),...?

Comment: Restricting to odd multiples of 3, this looks a lot like the original problem.  I will hazard the guess that it won't extend beyond 51, and likely not far beyond 35.